# fetch url links from json and add to listview

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to get url links of images from json response, save it to string[] using ArrayList and then display the images in gridview as shown in this [site](https://futurestud.io/blog/picasso-adapter-use-for-listview-gridview-etc). My json looks like this:[image]

I fetched the links using volley but I'm not getting the links properly. I checked the content of ArrayList using Toast and it shows the images inside [[]] like this:[image]

That's why the images are not getting downloaded. I get 6 blank views in list.

```html
MainActivity:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    String[] IMGS={};
    ArrayList<String> sal = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView listView;
    public static final String KEY_USERID = "user_id";
    private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://example.com/Services.php?action=fetchUserLog";




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        registerUser();
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);


    }

/////////////////////////////////////////  Volley Method Starts //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    private void registerUser(){

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        try {
                            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                            String status = jObj.getString("status");
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                            // Now check status value
                            if (status.equals("0")) {

                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There was some error! Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }else if(status.equals("1")){

                                // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Information saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                                JSONArray result = jObj.getJSONArray("results");
                                for(int i = 0 ; i < result.length() ; i++){
                                    JSONObject json_data = result.getJSONObject(i);
                                    sal.add(json_data.getString("images"));
                                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, sal+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    IMGS = sal.toArray(new String[sal.size()]);

                                    listView.setAdapter(new ImageListAdapter(MainActivity.this, IMGS));

                                }



                            } else {
                                // Error in login. Get the error message
                                String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // JSON error
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }



                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(KEY_USERID, "21");
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

/////////////////////////////////////////  Volley Method Ends ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



}
```

Comment: You used getString instead of getArray. You need to get the URL out of the JSON array...

Comment: Yes, I just saw that the image links are array not string object. So, should I use for loop again to get all the "images" Arrays? @cricket_007

Comment: Yeah, use getJSONArray like you did for results. Not sure if you need a loop since each array in your image has only one address

Comment: OK. Then how to add them to ArrayList and finally to IMGS[]?

Comment: Don't set the  `adapter` to the `listView` in a loop as this will overwrite your previous data. Save your  `Arrays` to an `ArrayList<Array>` (ArrayList of Arrays), edit your Adapter, and set the adapter after the loop!

Comment: You don't need IMGS. Just use the sal list for the adapter

Comment: Its working but I'm not getting the last image in the array. Any particular reason?

Comment: move your this `listView.setAdapter(new ImageListAdapter(MainActivity.this, IMGS));` out of loop